# How to withdraw the bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I asked a question and give a bounty for 50 points,i got only an answer which was not complete.Is it possible to withdraw that bounty for that question??

Comment: Your bounty has another 7 days on the clock, why the impatience?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, you cannot withdraw a bounty. Bounties are non-refundable. Note that bounties should be seen as *advertisement*, not a guarantee you'll get an answer you like.

If an answer did not help you (because it is wrong), consider downvoting that answer, and / or update your question to ensure that you better cover the issue if the answerer misunderstood you.

Comment: Then who will get that bounty reputations if the owner does not get it back? Do not tell me the person who gave an answer (which is not correct or helpful) will get it.

Comment: @Anand: under certain circumstances the top-voted answer will get half the bounty. See [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)