# Is it against the rules to link more of our posts in the bounty banner?

Tags: support, bounty, self-promotion, abuse

Starting bounties on questions we've asked, or on questions that we have answered [can be considered as self advertisement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367891/13552470).

I've no intention to do so, but is it against the code of conduct to link more of our posts as the custom message in the bounty banner?

Comment: Why would you do that? Bounty is the advertisement for the question receiving the bounty, not for the user posting the bounty.

Comment: @Dharman I wouldn't, but I want to know if it's against the rules.

Comment: I can't imagine that you would break any rule by doing so.

Comment: *Starting bounties on questions we've asked [...] is considered as self advertisement*. That is not really true and you appear to see this as something special? Bounties are most commonly set on your own questions, doing so is not seen as something out of the ordinary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299681/13552470

Comment: @AnnZen not sure why you are linking to that answer of mine. What has bounties being non-refundable have to do with anything? Moderators can cancel bounties, we do so in cases of abuse, not just because someone wanted it refunded.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Note that bounties should be seen as advertisement(s).

Comment: @AnnZen yes, but that term is not the same thing as “self-“ advertisement. You appear to be mixing terminology, or lumping in bounties on your question to get answers or bounties to get attention for your own answer in the same bucket. *Neither angle matters here*.

Comment: @Dharman Self promotion discussion.https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367891/13552470

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no explicit rule against that, no. However, if you did, it would *probably* backfire.

That’s because bounties are there to draw attention *to a specific question*. If you were to use them to point to several questions, I would expect the post to be flagged by someone for moderator attention soon enough as *someone* will see that as trying to turn bounties into something other than drawing attention to one question.

Many people are drawn to a question with a bounty by the prospect of *winning* the bounty. But, you can’t award the bounty to anything other than an answer posted to the bountied question; other questions linked are then just a distraction as the user would not gain anything from giving attention to those posts. Quickly, that’ll turn into disappointment and a suspicion that the bounty mechanism is being abused, etc. That disappointment and suspension could then easily lead to pointed comments, downvotes, and the aforementioned flags.

Better just *not try to use the bounty system to promote more posts*, really.

The *intention* for the bounty post banner is to serve as clarifications for the bounty on the specific question (to *clarify the expectations of the bounty winner*, as the message placeholder text explains), not for anything else.

Comment: The question is, will the flags be helpful, or declined?

Comment: @AnnZen that depends on the exact individual flag and banner text. Note that our *only* options are to leave the bounty be or to remove it, moderators can’t edit the message (the feature request is under review, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344145/140890). We have to take that into account when we assess each specific case.

Comment: @AnnZen that said: I myself would be inclined to remove the bounty if the banner text isn’t being used for its stated purpose however.

Comment: @AnnZen Rule of thumb: if the documented purpose of a feature doesn’t include a novel way of using that feature for promotion, *don’t use that novel way for promotion*.

Comment: Yes. But sadly, in reality, things that aren't written as against the rules might be done.